# Type of Affidavit to submit for Canada TRV application

Tags: visas, canada, paperwork, applications

i see some place where it stipulated that to make my application strong, i should have something like this, I should have sworn affidafit as it really helps submission for application, Now i want to understand, what type of Affidavit i should submit. I would like to know.

Comment: What exactly are you referring to?

Comment: @MichaelHampton , here is what i  mean. I am applying for Tourist visa to Canada. following this thread https://www.canadavisa.com/canada-immigration-discussion-board/threads/visitor-visa-affidavit.244314/ I see where they stipulated i need to have an Affidavit, since i am sponsoring myself , would there be any need to swear any affidavit again say i am the legal owner of my small business and all information i have provided are true in the court of Law. just asking to be quite sure so as to make no mistakes

Comment: That forum post said that such an affidavit would NOT be helpful. This is true; there is no point to it.

Comment: In other words, just my salary (As where i work full time) and then my business name registration certificate (This is where i work part time and have 4 employees (I do software development and deployment here and sell web hosting as well)), inclusive of bank statements and payslips would do just fine ? correct?

Comment: @Fred I’d consider adding your employment contract plus your tax return showing your business income

Comment: @Traveller good , could you be so kind as to enlist what you think i would be needing in order to have a strong application

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want to know what documents to submit with your Canada temporary resident visa application. These are listed in the official [document checklist](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/pdf/kits/forms/IMM5873E.pdf) published by Canada.

You should read the entire checklist, as it is a bit long to reproduce here. But it does mention (among other things) that you should submit:

> Copies of bank statements covering the past three months. Any additional relevant documentation (employment letter, pay slips, proof of pension, business registration, investments, etc.)
>
> Proof of Business if you are self-employed. Provide business registration, tax clearance certificates, trade certificates, license and financial documents, etc. (certified business bank account statement for past 6 months)
>
> Proof of employment - letter from your current employer and pay slips (last 3 months). Employment letter dated within 2 months of the application indicating occupation, job description, position, salary, allowances, years of employment and authorized leave dates.