# Using Sworn Affidavit as additional Document for Business name Registration for TRV Canada

Tags: visas, canada, paperwork, nigerian-citizens

in preparation for submission for TRV (Temporary residence Visa for Canada), I have gotten my business name registration document and I want to ask a question for the matter of Clarity. Basically i was asked to make available Business name registration document alongside other documents On the online application platform on IRCC Website.

Now i have my business name registration document (Company belongs to my father actually but he used my name in the opening / registration of the business), Now here is what i wanted to ask if i am on the right track. I went to the High court of Justice today to get a sworn affidavit confirming that i am the executive chairman of the company. Is there something I appear to be missing? or Do I still have to in detail have some other pending documents I must provide, asides Business Registration documents, Bank statements and the sworn affidavit compelling and convincing IRCC with regards to ties to home country?

Edit : I am from Nigeria

Comment: I see this question has received a vote to close as something that belongs on the Expatriates site. Take note that "Temporary Resident" [means](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/glossary.asp#temporary_resident_visa) "A foreign national who is in Canada legally for a short period", and Canada's "Temporary Resident Visa" is the appropriate visa for short-term travel purposes.

Comment: Running a business is only a strong tie to your home country if you have to be there to do it. In a previous question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/144185/type-of-affidavit-to-submit-for-canada-trv-application you said you do software development and web hosting. That type of business can inherently be done from pretty much anywhere.